# Azure DevOps Pipeline Test results contain Duplicate Test Cases

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, testng, azure-pipelines

If I go to Test results screen after run of my pipeline, it is showing each test case from Java/Maven/TestNG automated test project duplicated.  One instance of each test case shows blank for machine name and the duplicate of that shows a machine name.

[Run 1000122 - JUnit_TestResults_3662](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20v97.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. First, if you added multiple configurations to a test plan, if so, the tests cases will be repeated in the plan with the each of the configurations you have assigned.
Another possibility is that when you passed parameters to the test method, did you use multiple parameters, so the test method was executed two times.
The information you provided is not sufficient. Can you share the code or screenshots of your Test Samples?